# apache storm in cluster mode

Tags: java, maven, apache-kafka, apache-storm

i used apache storm to precessing data with kafka source, but where i run storm in cluster mode he return for me this erreur :
i user this commande line storm jar /path to my jar file args1

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Found multiple defaults.yaml resources. You're probably bundling the Storm jars with your topology jar.
at backtype.storm.utils.Utils.findAndReadConfigFile(Utils.java:106)
at backtype.storm.utils.Utils.readDefaultConfig(Utils.java:126)
at backtype.storm.utils.Utils.readStormConfig(Utils.java:146)
at backtype.storm.StormSubmitter.submitTopology(StormSubmitter.java:45)
at com.storm.Topologie.main(Topologie.java:48)
```

this my file dependencies in  pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
       <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
        <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.5</version>
        <!-- keep storm out of the jar-with-dependencies -->
        <scope>provide</scope>
    </dependency>
          <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
      <artifactId>storm-kafka</artifactId>
      <version>0.10.0</version>
      <type>jar</type>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
      <artifactId>kafka_2.9.2</artifactId>
      <version>0.8.1.1</version>
      <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
              <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
              <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
              <groupId>log4j</groupId>
              <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
  </dependency>
```

and the last part of my pom.xml

```
<build>
 <plugins>
   <plugin>
     <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
     <configuration>
       <descriptorRefs>
        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
       </descriptorRefs>
      <archive>
        <manifest>
         <mainClass>com.storm.Topologie</mainClass>
        </manifest>
      </archive>

     </configuration>
   <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>make-assembly</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
   </plugin>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<scope>provide</scope>
```

That "scope" isn't valid. The name is 'provided':

```
<scope>provided</scope>
```

Is your maven job successfully running with that pom.xml? Check, it's also likely that you're trying to publish the artifact (fat jar) from previously successful builds. Try executing the `clean` goal too.

Comment: thank you very much it works well, also I deleted defaults.yaml file in jara file  and it works

Comment: You can use the below command to delete the defaults.yaml from the jar      zip -d storm-example.jar defaults.yaml